# Warning! PATH is not properly set up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell, terminal

I updated my OS to Maverick and now I'm being hit with this error, any ideas how to fix this one? I'm sure it isn't completely necessary to fix it, however it's really annoying because it pops up every time I type a command.

Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p195'.

Updated

> >echo $PATH
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@glob‌​al/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/bi‌​n:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active‌​/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin

```
> echo ${PATH} | awk -v RS=: -v ORS='\n' '{print $0}'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
/usr/local/rvm/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/git/bin
/opt/sm/bin
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin
/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
```

Comment: Show output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: BTW, Did you attempt what the logs suggest `to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p195'` ?

Comment: Manav, echo $PATH = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin

Comment: Please update the question with the path. Also, please respond to my second comment.

Comment: Updated, and to the 2nd comment - for one it's a temp fix and two I'm using ruby-2.0.0-p247 not ruby-2.0.0-p195 as the comment recommends so I have chosen not to use it as I'd like a permanent fix and to be using  ruby-2.0.0-p247.

Comment: this question had an answer: [path is not set up solved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276701/getting-warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up-when-doing-rvm-use-2-0-0-defaul)