# Received Warning message "Path set to RVM" after updating ruby version using rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, oh-my-zsh

Recently I tried to update my ruby version due to a warning message (see below).

Now I get the following warning message when I start my iterm2:

```
Warning: PATH set to RVM ruby but GEM_HOME and/or GEM_PATH not set, see:
    https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3212
```

Does anyone know how to **resolve this warning?** It hasn't really impacted my work but it is a little unsettling.

for your information:
 1. I believed I ran `rvm get stable` to get the latest ruby version.
 2. this is the warning message I was initially trying to resolve but it has not been resolved either:

```
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby21, which recognizes
warning: 2.1.5-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.1.2.
```

I am using 1. `Mac OS X` 2. `iterm2` and 3.`oh-my-zsh` shell

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I had same issue with oh-my-zsh 
While installing rvm with option --rails, there was this warning:

This solution works for me:
Open `.zshrc` file, and find PATH line

change

`export PATH=/path/to/something`

into

`export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/something"`

save it and do `source ~/.zshrc`,
Then it worked.

Comment: thanks yi min, additionally I commented out this line:
`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.vm/bin"`

Comment: if this doesn't fix your problem check for a .zshenv as well.. on my debian laptop the PATH clobber export was there.  Took me forever to find it.

Comment: Where is `.zshrc` file stored?

Comment: .zshrc is at home, pun intented. ```~/.zshrc```

Comment: In Centos, I don't have .zshrc file, do I have to create it? because in .bashrc don't work ¿?

Answer (score 10):

If you find a line after `User configuration` in the ~/.zshrc file like this:

> #export PATH="/Users/robinwen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@robin/bin:/Users/robinwen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/Users/robinwen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/Users/robinwen/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/sw/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/"

You should comment this line, and add following line:

> export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

Good luck!

Comment: this worked for me on removing the same error received

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @ymin's solution. For me, who ran `rvm list` and did not have a current ruby selected, needs to manually select a ruby ie. `rvm use ruby-2.1.x`, then fix zshrc path and run `rvm get stable`.

Answer (score 4):

As of Dec 19, 2014, `sudo rvm` shows these PATH warnings when the root user's default shell is [not supported](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/c8a7818cd254f2592e76a4b1fd36a9603ea11de1/scripts/rvm#L18).

In this case of running `sudo rvm` the solution is to use [`rvmsudo`](https://rvm.io/integration/sudo).

Answer (score 2):

same issue here, add code below into `~/.zshrc` works for me.

```
export GEM_HOME="$GEM_HOME:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
export GEM_PATH="$GEM_PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

And then `source ~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question

my solution method is add

```
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

in .zshrc

source .zshrc is ok

good luck for you!

Answer (score 1):

After adding [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" to the top of ~/.zshrc rather than the bottom I can confirm this has solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I recently was facing this issue, every time I would use rvm or open a new terminal, I used to get this warning
I tried playing around with

> .bash_profile and .bashrc files
> but nothing was working

Even tried the commands - `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles` and `rvm reset`
but these also did not work

**turns out I had many paths defined in the**

> ~/.zshrc file

there were multiple entries for rvm, so comment out and added just one -:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```